# Failed to load template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am working my way through the tutorial on the Angular.js website in hopes of being able to integrate some of its powerful features into some of my existing applications. So everything has worked out just fine till I began working with the (angular route) portion. More specifically I've been unable to resolve an issue with my app failing to locate and load the necessary partials.

I figured the error might have something to do with the fact that the tutorial is not using the jade template engine but any variation i've made to the file path has proven unsuccessful. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

My file structure:

```
myApp
├── data
|   |-- contacts.json
|---public
│   ├── javascripts
│   │   ├── controllers
|   |       |---controller.js
|   |   |---app.js
|---views
|   |---partials
|   |   |---phone-list.jade
|   |   |---phone-detail.jade
|   |   |---contact.jade
|   |---index.jade
|   |---layout.jade
```

My code is as follows:

app.js :

```js
    'use strict';

/* App Module */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phonecatControllers'
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/phones', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list',
            controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
        }).
        when('/phones/:phoneId', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail',
            controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/phones'
        });
    }]);
```

My error messages :

```
GET http://localhost:3000/partials/phone-list 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Do you have the file `partials/phone-list`? That should be the HTML template

Comment: Where is the partials folder?? and the phone-list.html

Comment: Sorry, it was super late, when I wrote the question lol, but (yes I did already have the partials folder, I've appended it to the questions above.

Comment: I'm assuming you're working with an express application, which is being hosted from the root of the directory. Therefore a request to the partials would ideally be `/views/partials/phone-list'. However, there isn't a HTML file located there as it's a jade file and I believe you'll need to update your express logic to process and return the HTML when making a request with that URL possibly using a Regex.

Comment: Thank you. Is this a standard process in using the M.E.A.N stack? Could you possibly point me towards any documentation on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

According to your file structure, you don't have any *partials* folder

Comment: My apologies. My app did include the partials folder, it was my mistake not representing that properly in my question. I have appended the question to more accurately reflect the status of my application.

Comment: ok no worries, but I still can see some gaps between your code and the file structure.
http://localhost:3000/partials/phone-list is what you're calling but you should at least call http://localhost:3000/views/partials/phone-list, souldn't you? :)

Comment: When I attempted the revised file path I received the following error message:  `error.GET http://localhost:3000/views/partials/phone-list 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Any problem with the parsed file? There is actually an HTML version of the jade file?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. I was under the impression that jade files didn't get turned into html until they hit the browser. Is there a way for me to route to the parsed html file instead of the jade file?

Comment: I guess the problem could be the extension. Since you're using express the jade file will be "translated" in an HTML file, so just put the .html extension to the templateUrl string